# Calculate Distance via phase shift

Tags: measurement, distance, frequency-measurement, phase-shift

I see through phase shift we could calculate the distance. This is the principle inside laser rangefinder as well. But for this equation, I still do not know how it is derived.

$$
D=\frac {c* -1* \sum \limits_{N-1} \Delta \varphi_n }{4 \pi (N-1) \Delta f}
$$

I see 
$$
\Delta \varphi=\sum \Delta \varphi_i /N 
$$
$$
D=\sum  D_i /N 
$$
and from 1,2,3..N, there should be N-1 elements, but how this derived the that equation, especially why there is a -1 in the equation？

Related calculation and reasoning:
[Laser rangefinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_rangefinder) in the calculation section
[Measuring the Speed of Light](https://workspace.imperial.ac.uk/physicsuglabs/Public/1st_Year/Lab%20Manual/2014/Y1LabManual-11-SpeedOfLight-Corrected-20141029-12.10-GMT.pdf) in equation 11.7

Or actually we could see like this
Δφ=∑Δφi/(N−1)
then we can derive the equation, but there is an -1 in comparison with the original equation from the first link , which confuses me.

Comment: Where do you see that equation? Unless I missed something, it's not in either of the links you posted.

Comment: the output pulse is modulated at a certain frequency, the return pulse is measured and the phase shift between them is determined (time difference during a pulse period) and this equates to a distance - literally the wave length. The distance includes distance travelled there and back, so the actual distance is half of what is measured.

Comment: I see this from a ranging technology overview file, and links i post are what i think how this equation come from.

Comment: So what do the various terms represent. Nobody here is a mind reader dude.

Comment: @Andyaka Since in the original source, there's no any indication. As my knowledge, i think it is derived from the two links' equations. So, D=1/2*c*t, c is the speed of light, $$t=\varphi / 2 \pi f $$

Comment: @RogerRowland I re-edit the equation, i miss an n after the $$\varphi$$.

Comment: @KyranF Yes, you're explaining the principles   D=1/2*c*t right? But I do not get it how to derive from this, thank you:)

Comment: Don't bother leaving comments - edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: @Alex You're asking us to explain the derivation of an equation, right? If so, you also need to show the context. Where did you see that equation? What do the terms mean? What explanation was given? At the moment you just show two unrelated links but no link to the source of your confusion. Please show the original source *in context*.

Comment: @Alex the phase shift method of distance measurement is not related to the speed of light, that is for "time of flight" laser distance measurement. The distance is related to difference in pulse timing due to the fact light has travelled to a distance object and reflected before the receiver sees it. It's about steady state phase difference, and only really cares about inter-pulse timing and wavelength distance. Maybe I am confusing it but that's my take on it

Answer (score 1):

I guess i know why there's a -1 in the end, this is due to the relative shift. That is +D is regarding to -φ. Like D_ab is regarding to φ_ba. So D_ab is regarding to -φ_ab.

Comment: can you add this kind of thing into the main question please, rather than make an answer to your question which is really just you guessing/adding to the confusion?